# Python Tkinter Snip Tool, unable to create a transparent window then 50% transparent selection area

Tags: python, tkinter, tesseract

I want to create a snip tool with Python. The screen capture window should be 100% transparent, and only when the user selects an area will that area become translucent, let's say black with 50% opacity. I am unable to create a transparent background with Tkinter.

Here is what I have done till now -

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageTk
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'


class Overlay:
    def __init__(self, master: tk.Tk):
        self.master = master
        self.master.attributes("-topmost", True)
        # self.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", self.master["bg"])
        self.master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.master.attributes("-alpha", 0.1)
        # self.master.overrideredirect(True)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master=self.master, cursor="cross",
                                height=self.master.winfo_screenheight(), width=self.master.winfo_screenwidth(), bg="black")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.selection = None
        self.screenshot = None
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.onPress)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.onDrag)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.onRelease)
        # self.canvas.bind("<Escape>", self.removeOverlay)

    def configureOpacityTag(self):
        self.canvas.tag_configure("opaque", alpha=0.5)

    def onPress(self, event):
        self.x = self.master.winfo_pointerx()
        self.y = self.master.winfo_pointery()
        if (self.selection):
            self.canvas.destroy(self.selection)
        self.selection = None

    def onDrag(self, event):
        self.currX = self.master.winfo_pointerx()
        self.currY = self.master.winfo_pointery()
        if (self.selection):
            self.canvas.coords(
                self.selection, self.x, self.y, self.currX, self.currY)
        else:
            self.selection = self.canvas.create_rectangle(
                self.x, self.y, self.currX, self.currY, outline="black", fill="white")

    def onRelease(self, event):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.coords(self.selection)
        # print(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        self.master.destroy()
        selectedBox = (min(x1, x2), min(y1, y2), max(x1, x2), max(y1, y2))
        self.screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=selectedBox)
        # self.screenshot.show()
        print(pytesseract.image_to_string(self.screenshot))

    def capture(self):
        pass

    def removeOverlay(self, event):
        self.master.destroy()
```

Comment: You can create a *fake* transparent window by capturing the screen before opening the tkinter window (100% opaque), then show the captured screen in the canvas.  Then you can extract the image of the selected region and use `Pillow.ImageEnhance` module to make the extracted image look like *translucent* image and put that image at the selected region in the canvas.

Comment: Why did you comment out `self.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", ...)`? Did you try setting the `transparentcolor` to `"black"` as your canvas is black? If you try this approach, you should remove the `self.master.attributes("-alpha", ...)`